# How to create an AJAX request with JavaScript that contains both file and post data

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

How can I create a HTTP request that sends one file and some post data with JavaScript that can be received by a PHP server?

I have found the following suggestion but it does not seem to be complete

```
xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
var boundary = '---------------------------';
boundary += Math.floor(Math.random()*32768);
boundary += Math.floor(Math.random()*32768);
boundary += Math.floor(Math.random()*32768);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
var body = '';
body += 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary;
//body += '\r\nContent-length: '+body.length;
body += '\r\n\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n' + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="';
body += 'myfile"; filename="'+file.fileName+'" \r\n';
body += "Content-Type: "+file.type;
body += '\r\n\r\n';
body += file.getAsBinary();
body += '\r\n'
body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n' + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submitBtn"\r\n\r\nUpload\r\n';
body += '--' + boundary + '--';
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', body.length);
```

To get this working I need to have a 'file' variable that contains an input type file field but where to put additional post data? I want to send a description text as well. suppose I would also need to use xhr.send to send the request...

Answer (score 2):

Additional POST data should be placed as another Content-Disposition. Example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

Here two variables are sent: the file to be uploaded and a input with name = "submit-name" and value `Larry`. You could have as many Content-Dispositions as variables you would like to POST.

Of course much of the plumbing could be simplified if you used a js framework like jQuery. Here's an [excellent plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which should [do the job](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload).

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? It save you setting up your own XHR request.

Comment: I would like to know how to create a correct HTTP request with JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK It's not possible to send files with XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: It is certainly possible using base64.

Comment: You are free to add your answer to this question.

Comment: @ZippyV: sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773626/setrequestheader-content-type-causes-post-request-to-become-options my question answers this question. You are welcome to help me with my question.

Comment: No it doesn't. You cannot get the content of a file from a <input type="file"> object.

Comment: No you can't, but you can use `base64`. ah, wait. you even can get file content from file input, however, only in FF4.

Comment: You are talking about the File API which is still in a Working Draft stage. http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/