# Getting '400 Bad Request' when using multipart/form-data as Content-Type in XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, header, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I have an AJAX request that sends out some data. The data respects the multipart/form-data [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

The problem I'm facing is that the browser sets the Content-Type header to text/plain and it should be multipart/form-data.

I've tried doing this: `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` but this gives out an 400 Bad Request error.

If I do `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Typexxxx", "multipart/form-data");` there is no error, the "Content-Typexxxx" header is set but it obviously is no help to me.

I guess there is a list of valid Content-Type headers one can set and "multipart/form-data" isn't among them, but I cannot find a sollution to my predicament.

Sample of the data actually being sent:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=l3iPy71otz

--l3iPy71otz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="titluPublic"

Variation_1
--l3iPy71otz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nr_versiune"


--l3iPy71otz--
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think (hope) that [How to create an AJAX request with JavaScript that contains both file and post data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690611/) might be helpful. Otherwise, please post your code.

Comment: I've read the documentation and I'm pretty sure the request is valid, I just can't set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`. Unfortunately the other post didn't shine any light on my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't set the `boundary` in your request header, as in:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=l3iPy71otz");
```

For more information, see [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt):

> 5 Content-Type Header Field
> […]
>   Parameters are modifiers of the media
>   subtype, and as such do not 
>   fundamentally affect the nature of the
>   content.  The set of    meaningful
>   parameters depends on the media type
>   and subtype.  Most    parameters are
>   associated with a single specific
>   subtype.  However, a    given
>   top-level media type may define
>   parameters which are applicable    to
>   any subtype of that type.  Parameters
>   may be required by their    defining
>   content type or subtype or they may be
>   optional. MIME    implementations must
>   ignore any parameters whose names they
>   do not    recognize.
>
> For example, the "charset"
>   parameter is applicable to any subtype
>   of    "text", while **the "boundary"
>   parameter is required for any subtype
>   of    the "multipart" media type.**

**Update:** Another problem I found [on the net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/908d1f25-0b15-4b87-a711-6a667e5fad3d/#436f2bdd-09d3-4adc-833d-3b6fc7000c4d) appears when a `charset` is added to the `Content-type` in the request header, but not in the message boundaries in the body (this is also true for your test case). It doesn't seem a likely solution, but perhaps it helps.

In your case, explicitly add a `charset` to both the request header and in the message boundaries:

```
data.params += "--" + data.uniqid + "; charset=UTF-8" + data.crlf;
…
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + data.uniqid + "; charset=UTF-8");
```

**Update 2:** After trying this myself locally, I noticed the leading boundary wasn't recognized as such, but interpreted as the last parameter contents (on my more forgiving server). Perhaps that was causing Apache to throw a `400 Bad Request` error.

After some trial and error, I noticed that that was caused because the server expected the `charset` to be in *every* boundary, even the last one. To prevent confusion, I decided to explicitly set the `charset` in the request header *before* the boundary parameter, so that the boundary would be the last parameter in the `Content-type` request header. After this, everything seemed to work fine.

```
data.params = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + data.uniqid;
…
data.params += "--" + data.uniqid + data.crlf;
…
data.params += "--" + data.uniqid + "--";
…
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + data.uniqid);
```

Comment: the actual code is [here](http://clienti.bsorin.ro/florin2/cautare). just press the first action button (not the delete one :) ) and you'll see page I'm working on. If you submit the form (bottom of the page) you'll get the actual 400 error. The javascript file is [here](http://clienti.bsorin.ro/florin2/javascript.js) - I've commented near the part that generates the bad request error. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: @Sorin: Why do you explicitly set the `Content-length` to `8000`? AFAIK, you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I was just trying out different solutions. I took it out.

Comment: @Marcel: I added the charset, but it's still not working. I'm fairly new to javascript and ajax so you can immagine how frustrating this must be ..

Comment: @Marcel: just `[23/Jan/2011:01:13:53 +0200] "POST /florin2/request.php?action=produsUpdate&id=24556 HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://clienti.bsorin.ro/florin2/cautare" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"`

Comment: @Sorin: Now I see a 404, that's probably related to the unfound ErrorDocument; is there also a 400 error present? BTW, you're doing a POST request *and* you're sending URL parameters; though not technically wrong, there might be some problem with Apache/PHP. Can you try to omit the URL parameters and see if you get any `$_POST` variables in your server side script?

Comment: @Marcel: 400 error: `[Sun Jan 23 16:35:05 2011] [error] File does not exist: /home/soinro/!!clienti/400.shtml, referer: http://clienti.bsorin.ro/florin2/cautare`. I also left out the URL parameters, but this doesn't change anything

Comment: @Sorin: No, this isn't the line regarding the 400 error, but the line regarding the 404 error. BTW, why are you using `multipart/form-data` anyway, instead of sticking to the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for form data, where it is much easier to construct the POST data (only don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent`).

Comment: @Marcel: There are no other references to 400 errors. The script will have to support sending all sorts of data, not just text like it currently does.

Comment: @Sorin: In that case, can you post your server side code, so I (and other people here) can test this locally myself.

Comment: @Marcel: `request.php` is just `echo '$_SERVER[CONTENT_TYPE]='.$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'].'<br /><br />';
echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents('php://input').'</pre>';
debug($_POST);` where `debug()` is just a nicer `var_dump();`

Comment: @Marcel: Thanks for all the patience and support you've put into this. As it seems we couldn't figure out a solution I'll switch to the `x-www-form-urlencode` solution for now as I have to finish this job. Maybe at some point I'll get back to figuring this out and if I do I'll be sure to post the solution here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sorin: So my last update (#2) didn't solve your problem? Too bad... Anyway, you're welcome.