# setRequestHeader Content-Type causes POST request to become OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, facebook

**If you don't know the answer, thumbs up.**

```
function local_upload_photo(form_data)
{    
    var boundary    = "-----------------------------" + (new Date).getTime();
    var CRLF        = "\r\n";
    var parts       = [];

    // form text fields
    for(var i in form_data)
    {
        if(form_data.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            var part = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + i + '"' + CRLF + CRLF + form_data[i] + CRLF;

            parts.push(part);
        }
    }

    var data    = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAADElEQVQImWNgYGAAAAAEAAGjChXjAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');

    // photo file
    var part = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="me.gif"' + CRLF + "Content-Type: image/gif" + CRLF + CRLF + data + CRLF;

    //console.log( base64_encode(element.files[0].getAsBinary()) );

    parts.push(part);

    // prepare the query
    var request = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary + CRLF + CRLF; 
        // content-length is missing    
        request += "--" + boundary + CRLF;
        request += parts.join("--" + boundary + CRLF);
        request += "--" + boundary + "--" + CRLF;

    // send the data
    var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('post', 'http://upload.guy.com/storage.php');

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', String(request.length));


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }

    };

    // finally send the request as binary data
    xhr.sendAsBinary(request);
}
```

Story: the user comes to `guy.lt` and runs the JS code he is given in URL bar using `javascript:`. This should upload a file, the one you see in `base64` to `storage.guy.lt`. However, same origin policy kicks in here and does not allow it. One solution would be simply to ask people to do the same on storage.guy.lt or just move the upload guy.lt, however, client does not agree with that.

So after searching for a while I came across website Facebook. Now if you will monitor the process how FB uploads photos, you will notice that user does this from facebook.com, however POST request (as well using XMLHttpRequest, AFAIK) is sent to uploads.facebook.com. How do they do that?

In one place they load iframe `http://static.ak.facebook.com/common/redirectiframe.html` with content:

```
if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && !(parseInt((/Gecko\/([0-9]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent) || []).pop()) <= 20060508)) {
        //document.domain='facebook.com';
    }
```

I have tried doing similarly in my case, but this does not seem to have anything in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what the question is but here goes:

1. What you're seeing with the POST 'becoming' an OPTIONS request is [`preflighting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Preflighted_requests) - when making a cross-domain XHR request, the browser decides under certain circumstances (for example, when making a POST with the content-type set to something other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain`) to first check if the request will be allowed by the server before actually making it.
2. You haven't mentioned if you have control over the server-side of things but if you do, you have the option of responding to the `OPTIONS` request with

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://guy.lt
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
   ```

   to allow your JavaScript upload to go through.
3. The approach Facebook seems to be taking is that of setting the `document.domain` attribute which, if the parent window (www.facebook.com) and an iframe from another server on the same domain (uploads.facebook.com) set to the same value (facebook.com), scripts from each one can talk to the other<sup>[**1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sup>. This can be used to do cross-[sub]domain requests to the original domain of the window or the iframe. So the parent window from www.facebook.com can call JavaScript loaded from uploads.facebook.com in the iframe which will then allow requests back to uploads.facebook.com. [This blog post](http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/) describes this technique in more detail.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand JS "security" policy. I am on domain foo.com. I cannot POST multi-form data to bar.foo.com, however, what I can do, is dynamically create iframe on foo.com that loads bar.foo.com and append JS that IS permitted to post multi-part form data. Why then restrict to POST multi-form data from foo.com to bar.foo.com directly. :/

Comment: Well, think of this - if I host a site on `sites.google.com`; should my JavaScript be allowed to talk directly to `google.com`? In your case you see it as a problem because both the root domain and the subdomain are under your control, but in the case of `sites.google.com`, it's a good thing, from the point of security. But on the other hand, there is a valid use case for allowing this (your situation) and that's why browser makers have included this workaround, using `document.domain`.

Comment: ok, then why it is restricted while on `foo.com` to set `document.domain` to `bar.foo.com`?

Comment: The rule is that `document.domain` can only be set to a value that is a suffix of the site name and the smallest value can be the second level domain (i.e. the part before the TLD of .com, .org, .net etc). Again, security - it's obvious why it can't be changed arbitrarily to a different domain. But it can also be security issue to allow setting it to *any* arbitrary subdomain. Consider that `foo.com` is a hosting provider where you and I host sites - `bar.foo.com` and `baz.foo.com` respectively. If I can embed `bar.foo.com` in an iframe on `baz.foo.com` (which is legal) *and* ...

Comment: ..if I'm allowed to change `baz.foo.com`'s `document.domain`, I'm free to invoke any JavaScript on or ready any fields from (such as username/password or credit card fields!) your site via the iframe! That's not something you want to allow by default! However, if we *both* decide to set our `document.domain` values to `foo.com`, we can allow cross-scripting which can be useful. The idea is to have both parties agree to a common value and if the subdomain was allowed, that might not always be mutually agreed on. Setting to a smaller suffix is okay since the subdomain already belongs there.

Comment: Well, some of your arguments don't really make sense. For instance, if you are `foo.bar.com` and `bar.com` is your hosting company/sub-domain provider, they already have full access to your privacy.

Comment: @Guy (Sorry, if you don't use `@username`, notifications don't show up in the inbox so I missed this comment). I didn't mean protecting domain from the hosting provider (which, if you see the rules, happens already - unless `foo.bar.com` sets it's iframe domain to bar.com, bar.com cannot access it's internals)- I meant protecting from *other* subdomains on the same hosting provider. `foo2.bar.com` should not be able to access `foo.bar.com` since they may not necessarily be owned by the same person.