# How to catch files uploaded using ajax with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I've this JavaScript code to upload a file

```
// Uploading - for Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("post", "pro/upload.php", true);

// Set appropriate headers
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

// Send the file (doh)
xhr.send(file);
```

Now how do I catch the file at `upload.php`?

I tried with global `$_FILES["file"]` variable but an error says "Undefined Index". Does that mean the global variable is not set?

Comment: Can you update related HTML and PHP codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in Content-Disposition as well in setRequestHeader
Ref Link: [Content-Disposition Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690611/how-to-create-an-ajax-request-with-javascript-that-contains-both-file-and-post-d)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ajax file upload which is working perfect for me and it is easy to implement, If you like to work with jQuery please prefer this link.

```
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/
```